# Как сделать отмену действия?

Tags: javascript, html

В чём ошибка моего кода? Первая ветвь работает нормально, как сделать чтобы при повторном нажатии заработала и вторая ветвь?

```js
function checked()
{
  var ru_cy = document.getElementById('ru_cy');
  var kz_cy = document.getElementById('kz_cy');
  var kz_la = document.getElementById('kz_la');
  var check_lang = 0;
  if (check_lang == 0)
  {
    ru_cy.style.right = "6%";
    kz_cy.style.right = "6%";
    kz_la.style.right = "6%";
    check_lang++;
  } else if (check_lang == 1)
  {
    ru_cy.style.right = "-8%";
    kz_cy.style.right = "-8%";
    kz_la.style.right = "-8%";
    check_lang--;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="check_lang" onclick="checked()" value="0" id="check_lang">Выбрать язык</button>
<button class="ru_cy" id="ru_cy" onclick="ru_cy()">Русский - Кириллица</button>
<button class="kz_cy" id="kz_cy" onclick="kz_cy()">Казахский - Кириллица</button>
<button class="kz_la" id="kz_la" onclick="kz_la()">Казахский - Латиница</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых не `elif`, а `else if`, во-вторых в четвертой строке функции вы переменной `check_lang` всегда присваиваете 0, нужно вынести её объявление выше.

`right` на `backgroundColor` я заменил для наглядности

```js
var check_lang = 0;

var ru_cy = document.getElementById('ru_cy');
var kz_cy = document.getElementById('kz_cy');
var kz_la = document.getElementById('kz_la');

function checked() { 
  if (check_lang == 0) {
    ru_cy.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    kz_cy.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    kz_la.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    check_lang++;
  } else if(check_lang == 1) {
    ru_cy.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    kz_cy.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    kz_la.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    check_lang--;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="check_lang" onclick="checked()" value="0" id="check_lang">Выбрать язык</button>
<button class="ru_cy" id="ru_cy" onclick="ru_cy()">Русский - Кириллица</button>
<button class="kz_cy" id="kz_cy" onclick="kz_cy()">Казахский - Кириллица</button>
<button class="kz_la" id="kz_la" onclick="kz_la()">Казахский - Латиница</button>
```